# Why am I missing template mobile/home/index, application/index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning Ruby and I set up a controller like this:

```
class Mobile::HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end

  def create

  end

end
```

Which is very basic, and added a route like this:

```
 scope :module => :mobile, :as => :mobile do
    constraints(:subdomain => /m/) do
      resources :home
    end
  end
```

and when I try to see the page in the browser, I get this error:

```
Missing template mobile/home/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:haml, :erb, :builder]}. Searched in: * "/Users/alexgenadinik/projects/cmply/cmply-app/app/views" * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ckeditor-3.6.3/app/views" * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/app/views" * "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/devise-2.0.4/app/views"
```

but I have a view page here:

```
app/views/layouts/mobile/application.html.haml
```

Is the problem that I need to specify that I return the HAML format in my controller? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program tries to find a regular template, not the layout. Try to create the page:

```
app/views/mobile/home/index.html.haml
```

Comment: I just made that file, but it still gives the same error unfortunately.

Comment: actually I have my index.html.haml file in the app/views/layouts/mobile/home but you are saying not to put it into the layouts folder? How come?

Comment: BY the way it worked....I am just wondering if I was way off by putting anything in the layouts folder in the first place.

Comment: If you are planning to create different layouts for your mobile application then put some file here `app/views/layouts/mobile/home.html.haml` and mark as `= yield` in it the place where your `index.html.haml` and other files will be output. Also try to google "responsive design" -- current tendency make to your layout dynamic (like with ability to hide its parts that will be cumbersome on devices with a small screen).